How to apply SQLite patch?
I want to apply SQLite patch to fix vulnerability. In my environment, SQLite is a part of alpine-based image. So, I try to add line into my Dockerfike: fossil patch apply SQLite-0e4e7a05.sqlar , according to doc, but unfortunately I faced with error: current directory is not within an open checkout. After some googling, I figured out that I should change directory, but I don't understand which directory is correct? Is it correct way to apply security patch ?
